# Thingspeak upload and not saving value of AT command AT+CSQ responce

Tags: at-command

Below is the code that i upload values to thingspeak (nano,gsm900)

```
type here
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <String.h>
#include <DHT.h> 

 
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(3,2);
#define DHTPIN 8
 
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHT22);
int signal;
String response;
float humid;
float temp;

void getSignalStrength()
{
     // AT command 
  gprsSerial.print("AT+CSQ\r");
  delay(10);
  if(gprsSerial.available()>0){
    response = gprsSerial.readString();
    Serial.print(response);  
   delay(10);
 }
 int firstSpaceIndex = response.indexOf('+CSQ:');
 int lastCommaIndex = response.lastIndexOf(','); 
 if (firstSpaceIndex != 1 && lastCommaIndex != -1) {
    String tempsignal = response.substring(firstSpaceIndex + 1, lastCommaIndex);
    int sig= tempsignal.toInt();
     signal= sig;
    Serial.print(signal);
    response = "";
      }
}
void readdht()
{
      float h = dht.readHumidity();
      float t = dht.readTemperature(); 
      delay(100);   
       humid=h;
       temp=t;    
      /*Serial.print("Temperature = ");
      Serial.print(t);
      Serial.println(" °C");
      Serial.print("Humidity = ");
      Serial.print(h);
      Serial.println(" %");*/ 
}

  void ShowSerialData()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  delay(5000); 
  }
void connect()
{
  gprsSerial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CPIN?");
  delay(1000);
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CREG?");
  delay(1000);
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(1000);
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
  delay(1000);
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSTATUS");
  delay(2000);
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");
  delay(2000);
 
  ShowSerialData();
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CSTT=\"internet\"");//start task and setting the APN
  delay(1000);
 
  ShowSerialData();
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIICR");//bring up wireless connection
  delay(3000);
 
  ShowSerialData();
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIFSR");//get local IP adress
  delay(2000);
 
  ShowSerialData();
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSPRT=0");
  delay(3000);
 
  ShowSerialData();
  
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"api.thingspeak.com\",\"80\"");//start up the connection
  delay(6000);
 
  ShowSerialData();
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSEND");//begin send data to remote server
  delay(4000);
  ShowSerialData();
  
  String str="GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=xxxxx&field1= + String(temp) +"&field2="+String(humid)+"&field3="+int(signal);
  Serial.println(str);
  gprsSerial.println(str);//begin send data to remote server
  
  delay(4000);
  ShowSerialData();
 
  gprsSerial.println((char)26);//sending
  delay(5000);//waitting for reply, important! the time is base on the condition of internet 
  gprsSerial.println();
 
  ShowSerialData();
 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSHUT");//close the connection
  delay(100);
  ShowSerialData();
}
void setup()
  gprsSerial.begin(9600);       
  Serial.begin(9600);    
  delay(5000);
   dht.begin();
 delay(20000);
  }
 
void loop()
{
    readdht();
     getSignalStrength();
  if (gprsSerial.available())
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
     connect();
   delay(1000);
  }
```

temperature and humidity is usually updated (update every hour with an external circuit (turn on),24 hours looses 2-3 updates,
but signal is only updated when i connect and view the code with serial monitor, not working standalone with battery.

I Know delay is not the right way,but where could i add some more delay so it connects all times.
Why signal strenght is only updated when i run the code with serial monitor opened?
thanks

Not updating all times, not showing value of signal when not connected to serial monitor.